# Handling the required button checkbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having problem handling checkbox button in form using javascript.
I have created a form to collect customer information. In the form, in addition to the basic information such as first name, last name, email, ...at the end of the form  I have used a navigation tab panel to create 2 options.

The checkbox button in option 1 I have configured is mandatory to check

So my form can happen 2 cases as follows:

**Case1**:When the customer enters the basic information and chooses option 1, then check the checkbox and press the submit button (In this case, no problem)

**Case2:** After the customer enters basic information and selects option 2, the submit button cannot be pressed. (Because the checkbox in option1 has not been checked)

My question is :I Have to option [1][2] .In option 1 have to check in the checkbox and then I can submit the form . But if chooses option 2  I dont want check the checkbox and I want to how to submit the form .

Because my project code is too long, I used a W3C code as an example for my problem.Hope you guys can help me

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<body>
<form>
<div class="w3-container">
  <h2>Example</h2>

</div>

<div class="w3-bar w3-black">
  <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="openCity('London')">London</button>
  <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="openCity('Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="openCity('Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="w3-container city">
  <h2>London</h2>
  <p><input type="checkbox" requied >London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="w3-container city" style="display:none">
  <h2>Paris</h2>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="w3-container city" style="display:none">
  <h2>Tokyo</h2>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
<script>
function openCity(cityName) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("city");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";  
}
</script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels sorry it's my fault i edited to javascript

Comment: We don't need to see your entire project. There's a huge amount of CSS here that's not relevant. See [mcve]

Comment: Additionally, having that many required fields makes it hard for us to debug.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular Here is the CSS for the form . As for the part for the checkbox, I don't know how to write script it. Hope you help

Answer (score 0):

This problem was easily solved with javascript. Why do you rate this article -3

```html
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document</title>
      <style>
         *{
         margin:0px;
         padding: 0px;
         }
         body{
         width: 100%;
         height: auto;
         background-color: white;
         }
         table,td,tr{
         padding:5px;
         }
         table{
         max-width: 700px;
         margin:auto;
         display: table;
         background-color: #eee;
         }
         td{
         display: table-cell;
         font-size: auto;
         }
         input[type=checkbox]
         {
         /* Double-sized Checkboxes */
         -webkit-transform: scale(1.3, 1.3)
         }
         #seireki{margin-left: 34px;}
         #title{
         font-weight: 900;
         }
         /* button */
         .disable{pointer-events:fill}
         label{position:relative}
         label:after{
         position: absolute;
         content: "";
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         }
         .button-group-item{
         border-radius: 1px solid gray;
         }
         /* button */
         .main input[type=radio] {
         display: none;
         }
         p span{border-bottom: 1px solid gray;}
         #tab-1:checked ~ .tab label:nth-child(1),
         #tab-2:checked ~ .tab label:nth-child(2),
         {
         background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
         box-shadow: none;
         }
         .content > div {
         display: none;
         width: 476px;
         margin-top: 5px;
         height: 237px;
         }
         #tab-1:checked ~ .content div:nth-child(1),
         #tab-2:checked ~ .content div:nth-child(2)  {
         display: block;
         }
         .main {
         margin-top: 20px;
         max-width: 800px;
         height: auto;
         }
         .tab {
         overflow: hidden;
         label {
         font-size: 18px;
         cursor: pointer;
         float: left;
         color: #fff;
         width: 25%;
         text-align: center;
         padding: 15px 0;
         text-transform: uppercase;
         font-weight: bold;
         letter-spacing: 2px;
         box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
         user-select: none;
         -webkit-user-select: none;
         }
         }
         .content {
         min-height: 250px;
         > div {
         padding: 30px;
         line-height: 1.5;
         font-size: 17px;
         }
         }
         /* small_table */
         .content-dis{
         border:1px solid gray;
         height: auto;
         padding-left: 5px;
         }
         input[type="submit"] {
         width: 100px;
         background: #27AE60;
         font-weight: bold;
         color: white;
         border: 0 none;
         border-radius: 1px;
         cursor: pointer;
         padding: 10px 5px;
         margin: 10px 5px;
         }
         input[type="submit"]:hover, input[type="submit"]:focus {
         box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #27AE60;
         }
      </style>
      
   </head>
   <body>
      <form action="https://www.google.com/" method="post">
         <table>
            <tr>
               <td id="title" rowspan="1">決済条件<br><span>(ご希望の口欄<br>に選択して<br>下さい)<span></td>
               <td>
                  <div class="main">
                     <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="show" checked/>
                     <input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="show" />
                     <div class="tab">
                        <button type="button" id="button-left" name="button-group" value="item">
                        　<label for="tab-1"  id="tab-1" >
                        <input type="radio" name="button-group" value="item" checked>
                        <span class="button-group-item">銀行振込</span>
                        </label>
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" id="button-right">
                        <label for="tab-2"  id="tab-2" >
                        <input type="radio" name="button-group" value="other-item">
                        　　  <span class="button-group-item">口座振替</span>
                        　     </label>
                        </button>
                     </div>
                     <div class="content">
                        <div class="content-dis">
                           <p>
                              締切日 
                              <select class="" name="deadline">
                                 <option value="20日">20日</option>
                                 <option value="末日">末日</option>
                              </select>
                           </p>
                           <p>
                              希望支払日 
                              <select class="Desired_payment_date" name="Desired_payment_date">
                                 <option value="20">20日</option>
                                 <option value="21">21日</option>
                                 <option value="22">22日</option>
                                 <option value="23">23日</option>
                                 <option value="24">24日</option>
                                 <option value="25">25日</option>
                                 <option value="26">26日</option>
                                 <option value="27">27日</option>
                                 <option value="28">28日</option>
                                 <option value="29">29日</option>
                                 <option value="末">末</option>
                              </select>
                           </p>
                           <p>
                              <select class="bank" name="Bank_transfer_destination">
                                 <option value="福井銀行">福井銀行</option>
                                 <option value="北陸銀行">北陸銀行</option>
                                 <option value="敦賀信用金庫">敦賀信用金庫</option>
                                 <option value="商工中金">商工中金</option>
                                 <option value="滋賀銀行">滋賀銀行</option>
                                 <option value="三菱UFG銀行">三菱UFJ銀行</option>
                              </select>
                           </p>
                           <p><input type="checkbox" name="test" value="" id="myCheck" >振込手数料の負担に同意します。</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="content-dis">
                           <p>
                              締切日 
                              <select class="" name="deadline_Account_transfer">
                                 <option value="">20日</option>
                                 <option value="">末日</option>
                              </select>
                           </p>
                           <p>引落日 ：翌月２７日(固定)</p>
                           <p>※振替日が休日の場合は、翌営業日となります。</p>
                           <p>※営業日とは、金融機関窓口営業日です。</p>
                           <p>※全国の金融機関がご利用できます。</p>
                           <p><span>※講座振替の場合は、手数料のご負担は</span></p>
                           　
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;"> <input type="submit"  onclick="myFunction()"></input></td>
<!--  document.getElementById("myCheck").required = false; -->
            </tr>
         </table>
        <script>
            function myFunction() {
              if(document.getElementById("tab-1").checked){
                   document.getElementById("myCheck").required = true;
              }
              else if(document.getElementById("tab-2").checked){
                document.getElementById("myCheck").required = false;
              }
            }
            </script>

      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```